# How to write some transit-clj in a file and how to retrieve the data structure from this file

Tags: json, clojure, transit

Say I have:

```
(def c [{:id 12 :name "John"}])
```

How do I write this in a file?

How do I get back this data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A not perfect solution that works:

```
(require '[clojure.java.io :as io]
         '[cognitect.transit :as t])

(def c [{:id 12 :name "John"}])

(def dir "resources/json/")

(defn write-transit [dir file-name file-type coll]
  (let [suffix {:json ".json" :json-verbose ".verbose.json" :msgpack ".mp"}]
    (with-open [out (io/output-stream 
                      (str dir "/" file-name (file-type suffix)))]
        (t/write (t/writer out file-type) coll)))))

(defn read-transit [dir file-name file-type]
  (let [suffix {:json ".json" :json-verbose ".verbose.json" :msgpack ".mp"}]
    (with-open [in (io/input-stream (str dir "/" file-name (file-type suffix)))]
      (t/read (t/reader in file-type)))))

(write-transit dir "test" :json c)
;=> nil

(read-transit dir "test" :json)
;=> [{:id 12 :name "John"}]
```

Comment: It is worth noting: Transit is intended primarily as a wire protocol for transferring data between applications. If storing Transit data durably, readers and writers are expected to use the same version of Transit and you are responsible for migrating/transforming/re-storing that data when and if the transit format changes. (source Transit website)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the code in the doc to [read](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/read), especially at the bottom.
There's a complete example of what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I believe the answer should use `cognitect.transit/read` and `cognitect.transit/write` functions though. See https://github.com/cognitect/transit-clj